# How to stop player to connect current running game in unity5.?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, multiplayer, unity-networking

How can I stop new player connection after game start. I have max 4 player connection limit and a timer of 10 seconds before game start. If 3/2 Player connected and game start then 4th player will be empty (means game start with 3 or 2 player). after game start 4th player should not connect. he/she need to wait for next round.

Game ip address is `localhost` and port is `7777`. so 4th player will not connect to this address.

THis is my network connection code.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.Networking;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Network_Manager_Custom : NetworkManager {

    private Animator anim;
    //[SerializeField]private GameObject btnDisconnect;

    public void StartupHost()
    {       
        setPort ();
        NetworkManager.singleton.StartHost ();
        //Debug.Log ("I am calling from startupHost.!");
    }

    public void JoinGame()
    {
        setIPAddress ();
        setPort ();
        NetworkManager.singleton.StartClient ();
    }
    public void setIPAddress()
    {
        string IPAddress = GameObject.Find ("InputFieldIPAddress").transform.FindChild("Text").GetComponent<Text>().text;
        NetworkManager.singleton.networkAddress = IPAddress;
        Debug.Log ("IPAddress : "+ IPAddress);
    }
    void setPort()
    {
        NetworkManager.singleton.networkPort = 7777;
    }
    void OnLevelWasLoaded(int level)
    {
        if (level == 0) {
            SetupMenuScreenButtons ();
        } else {
            SetupOtherSceneButtons ();
        }
    }
    void SetupMenuScreenButtons()
    {
        GameObject.Find ("btnStartHost").GetComponent<Button>().onClick.RemoveAllListeners();
        GameObject.Find ("btnStartHost").GetComponent<Button> ().onClick.AddListener (StartupHost);

        GameObject.Find ("btnJoinGame").GetComponent<Button>().onClick.RemoveAllListeners();
        GameObject.Find ("btnJoinGame").GetComponent<Button> ().onClick.AddListener (JoinGame);
    }
    void SetupOtherSceneButtons()
    {       
        //btnDisconnect = GameObject.Find ("btnDisconnect");
        //if (btnDisconnect != null) {
            GameObject.Find ("btnDisconnect").GetComponent<Button> ().onClick.RemoveAllListeners ();
            GameObject.Find ("btnDisconnect").GetComponent<Button> ().onClick.AddListener (NetworkManager.singleton.StopHost);
        //} else {
        //  Debug.Log("btnDisconnect not available.!");
        //}
    }
}
```

Any one can help me here.?

How can I do this.? How to stop player to connect current running game.?

Comment: Set `NetworkManager.maxConnections` to the number of current connections when game starts then reset it to 4 at the end of the game. I can't put this as an answer because I've not done it before and can't verify if it works or not.

Comment: I set it from inspector.

Comment: Do what I just said from code. You can't do most stuff from the Editor.